# The usage of "...that one might assume"

Tags: orthography, descriptive-grammar

I have a question about the following sentence. In the (A) option, I'm aware that's a classical "as .... as you assume". But my main confusion is that (B) option seems really legit to me gramatically. Like in this context:

"...modern societies are not so different from primitive societies, that one might assume. But that's not occasionally true."

As there is no additional information following this sentence, I think both options are okay. Though I'm not sure whether a comma is a must before "that one might assume" or just optional. Or it's even possible I'm all wrong about the option (B). I just thought some help could be good to sort this thing out, thanks!

> When it comes to the environment, modern societies are not ...... different from primitive societies ...... one might assume.
>
> A) as/as
>
> B) so/that

Comment: It seems to be a typo for _as_. And in the second sentence _not occasionally true_ is very strange; that seems to be a thinko for _occasionally not true_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B is definitely NOT correct. While you are on the right track that "SO" can work for the first position, there's a problem using "THAT" in the second.

The resulting text: "...modern societies are not SO different from primitive societies THAT one might assume." is actually a sentence fragment.

"THAT" in this context introduces a  question "THAT one might assume..." what? What might one assume? It leaves an incomplete thought.

So A is correct.

I'm speculating if you're not a native English speaker, perhaps you're confusing THAT with THAN; replacing the second gap with THAN would, in fact, work.

"When it comes to the environment, modern societies are not SO different from primitive societies THAN one might assume."

Comment: I guess I thought "that" might refer to the whole sentence at the beginning. Like: One might assume that when it comes to the environment, modern societies are not so different from primitive societies. But in this case:  "when it comes to the environment, modern societies are not so different from primitive societies" that one might assume. I understand that it's not correct and thank you so much! Just one more quick question, I got confused because it reminds me the way of a TV news reporter read the news. Is it possible to quote something and later add any "that one assume" sentence?

Comment: If I understand your question, again I'd say you want the "...THAN one might assume." clause in that context.